# qt - In QGraphicsScene how to catch a particular item

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicspixmapitem

I have so many things in my `QGraphicsScene`. The situation is I am creating a chessboard, and is using Graphics scene. So the `QGraphicsScene` is having so many `QGraphicsPixmapItems`. Now In this how can I get the King.

**Update:**
   In this `QGraphicsScene`, I am adding `QGraphicsPixmapItems` which are nothing but coins(board,king,queen,soldiers,etc).  Now if I want to move a particular coin say King, then How can I get it. There are some methods like using iterators. But is there any way to find a particular `QGraphicsPixmapItem` by it's name.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the King"? Please put it in defined and programming way.

Comment: coins ? are you referring to pieces ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you need to get the King, how do you make the difference in your program between the white King and the black one ?

If you need to get a Pawn, how do you know which one ? Anyone ? The first one you can find in your items ?

I haven't thought a lot about it, but maybe what you can do is using a QMap. The key would be a enumeration of the different pieces and the value would be a pointer to the relevant `QGraphicsItem`. Something like this :

```
enum Piece_e {
    KING,
    QUEEN,
    ROOK1,
    ROOK2,
    ...
    PAWN1,
    PAWN2,
    ...
};

QMap<Piece_e, QGraphicsPixmapItem*> WhitePiecesItems;
QMap<Piece_e, QGraphicsPixmapItem*> BlackPiecesItems;
```

When you are creating your scene and instanciating your pieces, you'll fill the map :

```
...
WhitePiecesItem[KING] = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("whiteking_pic"));
WhitePiecesItem[PAWN1] = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("whitepawn_pic"));
...

BlackPiecesItem[QUEEN] = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("whitequeen_pic"));
BlackPiecesItem[PAWN1] = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("whitepawn_pic"));
...
```

When you need to find the object corresponding to the white king, you could do something like this :

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem* pItem = WhitePiecesItem[KING];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Instead of map I kept two vectors.